# ? Card destroys Blank card

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I was playing greed mode and I got Jera, Blank card and glitter bombs. During the greed fight, I dropped a bunch of bombs and started spamming Jera and the room was filled with shit. I picked up some other cards including ? card and when it was all over, my blank card wasn't there. There's no way for items or chests to spawn from glitter bombs and it wasn't replaced (I had no spacebar item afterwards). My theory is that when I used ? card, Blank card disappeared. Has anybody tried this or can confirm?
Here's a picture of me, in my sea of items with my blank card missing:

[image: I'm very large :)]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interaction between [*Blank Card*](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Blank_Card) and [*? Card*](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/%3F_Card) is known, and it does destroy both. It is supposed to also teleport you to the [*I AM ERROR*](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/I_AM_ERROR) room, which the wiki page on the *? Card* suggests is because resolving the infinite loop that you might think would result from using the two items together is somewhat paradoxical and thus would cause an error.

I would imagine that, similar to *The Chest* and *Dark Room*, the *Ultra Greed* floor has no *I AM ERROR* room so the teleportation was not able to actually occur. It may have spawned the *I AM ERROR* shopkeeper, but it's possible they're off the top of the screen or hidden behind you or Ultra Greed in the screenshot.